# Swift: Localize a string contains plurals determined by a double variable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, localization

I'd like to localize the title of a Stepper View as follows: "1 hour", "1.25 hours", "3.50 hours".

I created a Localizable.stringsdict as below:

[image]

Then I created a ContentView as below:

[image]

(**Source code** you can find on [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/projectxmaker/85a3cba804876c4c2a25f9082f370a60))

But what displays on the preview is "1.000000 hour", "1.250000 hours" or "3.750000 hours".

[image]

I tried format sleepAmount as below but the preview now displays "1.25 hour" (the expected one is "1.25 hours") because this change broke the plural rule which only accepts int, double or float.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found the solution. In your `.stringsdict` file instead of `%lf hours` use `%.2f hours` and when you print the variable use `"\(sleepAmount) hour"` without the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this function and see if it is useful, and will allow the same concept to be used in other places, and will keep the code clear and concise as the point where it is needed:

```
func plural(_ count: Int, _ word: String) -> String { 
    let locval: String.LocalizationValue = "^[\(count) \(word)](inflect: true)"
    return String(AttributedString(localized: locval).characters)
}
```